# Eclipse git commit started defaulting comment text to " Change-Id: I0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"?

Tags: eclipse, git

Where is this coming from and where's the setting to turn it off?

```
Change-Id: I0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It started showing up in Git commit ... Eclipse neon.3

*UPDATE*

Clicking the icon on the top-right of the commit window makes this go away, but then it comes back at the next commit.

Here are my settings

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved in git command-line: `git config --unset gerrit.createchangeid`

Where did this setting come from originally and how did it get to my machine? No idea.

Answer (score 2):

Change-Id is usually used in gerrit.

So you don't use gerrit, change-id is unnecessary.

[image]

When you commit your source code, This icon can turn off Change-id.

Comment: Any ideas how to permanently turn this off? It keeps coming back and I have to click that silly icon every time.

Comment: Can you capture properites?(Window -> Preferences -> Git -> commit Dialog)

Comment: You can permanently turn this off. Edit git config (gerrit.createchangeid is false ) .  git config --global gerrit.createchangeid false

Comment: Changing setting in CLI didn't help. I attached a screenshot of eclipse settings.

Comment: Can you attach git config file? (system git config file, golbal git config file, project git config file) or If you use cli, attach result( git config --list ).